# Forcing viewDidLoad to be called again after pushing to a new UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar controller with 2 tabs in it.

Tab 1 gets started and I click on tab 2. In the UIViewController inside of Tab2 is a button that gets pushed with a UINavigationController. This all worrks fine. But when I hit back I want to force TabBarController class to call viewDidLoad again.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: What about `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is, well, loaded. You can call it yourself from one of other methods that get called, but I can hardly see any point in doing that.

Comment: is there anyway to add a button to a tabbar that shows and hides when you hideBottomTabBar?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

If you want to do something each time tab 1 is shown you have to use `viewWillappear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Check Responding to View Events on Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/).